# on view page load execute controller function, angularjs way

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

Inside angularjs view I want to call controller function. This function shuold be called on page load. Should I follow classic syntax like in asp.net mvc razor view forexample (using ajax) or there is some angularjs specific way to do this?

Comment: Just refer to ng-init directive

Answer (score 3):

Anything done at page load should be done in the controller itself or in a directive definition, not in the view.